# Export Data to powerpoint and download slide from java Spring MVC maven Application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, maven-3

I need to Export data from Mysql database as powerpoint slides and to be format it and download automatically from the web application when click the button using java Spring MVC -  maven application.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is waaaay too broad! Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You may use a reporting tool for this.
Ex: `BIRT`, `Jasper`